# Problem with validating forms with both Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

Okay, so I want to validate a form with Javascript before I validate it with PHP. If the Javascript function, let's call it validate(), detects an error, I want to prevent the PHP from being executed.

There is only one way that I know of which would enable me to do so: 
Using a link instead of a submit button, like this:

```
<a href="javascript:validate()">Login </a>
```

This could be the function validate():

```
function validate() {
//Do all the validation
document.form_name.submit(); }
```

However, there is one problem with this: My PHP scripts cannot know when exactly the form is submitted. Without Javascript, I would do this:

```
if ($_POST[button_name])
```

Now, though, there is no submit button, so the expression becomes obsolete.

So, in summary my question is:

**How can I validate a form with Javascript and prevent the PHP validation from being executed if there is an error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a submit button, so that even the users without js enabled can still send the form, and it will be validated by php.

With js you can prevent the form submission, then check for validation and submit after you have validate it correctly.

Comment: How do I prevent the submission? That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: <form action="process.php"
onsubmit="return validate(this)">

Comment: return false if the js validation fails.

Comment: And that prevents the form submission?

Comment: yes, in your validation function you have to return false if the validation is not correct, and it will prevent submission.

Comment: It doesn't work! I have an onsubmit function that returns false, but all my fields are still cleared! Can that be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

> There is only one way that I know of which would enable me to do so: Using a link instead of a submit button

There's a `submit` event on forms for exactly this purpose. You hook the event, and if the form is not valid, cancel the submission. Then you can use a submit button.

Comment: Exactly. Try putting the button there. Use `onsubmit='validate()'` inside the `form` tag.

Comment: I was going to use that, but once the form is submitted I don't think that I can stop the PHP script through Javascript.

Comment: Don't use `onsubmit='validate()'` since (1) It doesn't return anything so won't cancel the event and (2) It isn't [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: @user805556 — the form won't be submitted until the submit event has finished executing, and then only if the event handler doesn't cancel it.

Comment: @user: The `submit` event is client-side. If you cancel the event, nothing is sent to the server at all. Your PHP code won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't submit the form unless valid.

```
 function validate() {

     var isValid = true;
     //Do all the validation
     if(isValid)
     {
        document.form_name.submit(); 
     }
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I said in the question, but I stated above why that won't work for me.

Comment: All the submit button does is send a variable to the server with the submit button's name and value. The same can be done with a hidden input in the form <input type=hidden name='submitBtn' value='valid'>. The above code only calls the form submit if the validation passes. It is the same as returning false on the submit button action. If you have the hidden input and look for that you know to validate the request. Sorry I didn't understand the issue very well if this is still not what you are looking for.

Comment: It is what I was asking for, and I'll look further into hidden inputs. I heard of them before, but didn't see a reason for their existence until now.

Comment: hidden inputs are ways to pass additional params to the server rather than having them all in the form's address. They are useful when you don't have all the information contained in the form that you need.

Answer (score 0):

use onsubmit="return validate()" to validate html form or submit a form using submit(); a javascript method